# Is there a way to use variables with the AWS CLI for SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, command-line-interface, amazon-ses

I am using the aws cli to send some emails via sns and in the shell script I'm running to do that I have declared some variables, STATUS_DOWN_HOST and STATUS_DOWN_ENV. The main "meat" of my script then runs the below:

> aws sns publish --topic-arn
>   arn:aws:sns:ap-southwest-2:377766644499:URL_TEST --message "The
>   service $STATUS_DOWN_HOST is unresponsive on $STATUS_DOWN_ENV."

This sends a mail as intended but the variables are not picked up so the email message just appears with those parts omitted.

Are there some quotes or brackets I should be using so the cli picks up the variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to test if the vars are set by running `echo "The service $STATUS_DOWN_HOST is unresponsive on $STATUS_DOWN_ENV."`?

Comment: I have tested the same and it worked. check the variables.

Comment: Even after say:

Comment: export STATUS_DOWN_HOST=myhost.com

Comment: export STATUS_DOWN_ENV=INT_TESTING

Comment: And then, after that, you get: The service myhost.com is unresponsive on INT_TESTING.

Comment: Ah okay - maybe if yours is working... perhaps it's not working on mine because multiple hosts are down and the variable would have multiple values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `printenv` command to include environment variables into your output.

The $() syntax will allow you to imbed the command.

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:ap-southwest-2:377766644499:URL_TEST --message "The service $(printenv STATUS_DOWN_HOST) is unresponsive on $(printenv STATUS_DOWN_ENV)."
```

**References**

[printenv man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printenv.1.html)
[Unix & Linux - What is $() in a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147420/what-is-in-a-command)